Problem in building docker image using jib Plugin
I am using Google jib to generate the image for my maven project
and I also added the jib dependency in pom.xml for my maven project.
But my docker image is not building, It is giving me an error of Unsupported class file major version 66 ->
So this is my pom.xml build part
       <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>openjdk:22-jdk-slim</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>ayushgh2001/${project.artifactId}:s4</image>
                </to>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>22</source>
                <target>22</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

I added the dependency of jib plugin and also configure it to use image of jdk:22 version
But whenever i am running this command mvn compile jib:dockerBuild, I am getting error in my terminal , I attached the image of error i am getting
Terminal Image

Did you google that error? Classfile version 66 is java 22, apparently the jib-maven-plugin doesn't run on Java 22 due to some old ASM inclusion. So run using an older JDK.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Yeah it is resolved now, I downgraded the version of JDK and it worked. Thanks
